# Can I see where I'm touching my trackpad on the screen and whether it's being interpreted as a right or left click?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, ui

As a way of addressing [Is there a spatial map for 2020 MacBook Air track pad's right-click "sweet-spot"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/397272/143729) I was wondering if I can see in real time on my screen what my trackpad "sees", or more accurately, what it detects and interprets.

Is there a way to display the location that a single finger "click" on my 2020 MacBook Air's track pad is interpreted, and whether it's assigned as a right or left click?

Comment: The Apple trackpad is very different from PC trackpads (especially like HP) where physical location determines whether you right or left click.  Apple’s is based on [multi-touch gesture](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/trackpad-gestures-ipad66ce6358/ipados) so it’s location is irrelevant.

Comment: @Allan If I were a developer I'd write a short bit of code [along these lines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html) but I'm not. However if there were a Python package that access these tools then I'm willing to try! (maybe [Kivy](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/)?)

Comment: I didn't say your question is irrelevant, I said the *location* is irrelevant.  And whether it”s single click, double click, right click, etc, it’s based on gesture.  I referenced PC because it is based on location meaning it parallels your question.  I also didn’t say the location couldn’t be calculated, I’m inferring that it’s not done. I didn’t ”t write an answer because I don’t know if a trackpad event viewer exists or not.  Now, it would be nice if you wouldn’t take this as personal but a correction of what is perceived  to be a misunderstanding of how the trackpad works.

Comment: @Allan okay but I'm not yet convinced that I don't understand how the trackpad works, at least to some useful extent. I'm familiar with gestures but when I tap or click I'm pretty sure at some lower level within the trackpad hardware a location will be continuously calculated at some reasonable rate. Later on when the data is interpreted as a gesture, that's UI stuff. But to generate the map that I've discussed in the question, I'm after the lower-level position data in the hardware, and they may or may not be a viewer for that.